# Deploying JS apps to Windows 8 gets resources.pri access denied error

Tags: javascript, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to run my apps, but it is suddenly getting this error.  I don't know why.  I haven't changed anything.

**Error 3   Error : DEP0500 : The folder "C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\App2\App2\bin\Debug\AppX" could not be deleted. 
Access to the path 'resources.pri' is denied,**

I'm running VS2012 as Administrator and I've removed everything from the debug directory.  I can't find anything on how to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure all instances of your app, including those in the simulator are terminated?

Comment: I would elevate, blow away the Bin & Bld directories in C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\App2\App2, and then try deploying again.

Comment: Yes!  It wasn't the bin folder or the Run as admin, it was the Bld folder.  I deleted Debug and Release from it and all was well.  Thanks!

Comment: Crap, its back and won't go away.  I can't quite figure out how to get past.  Frustrating.

Comment: And the same solution doesn't fix it?
Are you using RTM, or RC?
OH, I see. Why are you running VS elevated? There should be no reason to do that. I suspect thats causing some of the permissions relating to AppContainer and loose package deployement to get terribly confused.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't fix it.  I'm RTM.  I was only running VS as elevated to try and troubleshoot this issue.  I've submitted the issue to VS2010 support team.  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770036/access-to-the-path-resources-pri-is-denied-when-trying-to-run-a-windows-8-app-in-debug-or-release-mode#tabs

Comment: Looks like a reboot of the machine fixes it, at least temporarily.  It just keeps coming back.  I try to delete the resources.pri file directly, but it won't let me.  Some process has a hold of it and won't let go.

Comment: You should use the sysinternals process explorer, and see which process has a handle on the file. That'll point to the culprit.

Comment: I'll try that as my problem continues.  Thanks Dominic

Comment: I have the same problem here; logging off fixes the problem most of the time, but sometimes I need to reboot. I haven't found any other workaround.

Comment: Are you running this app in a virtualized environment, especially Parallels? See this thread: http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=267785

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a bug with Parallels.  If you kill prl_cc.exe the files should be unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows on Mac with Parallels, it seems to be a known issue and there is a workaround here:

http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?267785-Parallels-Control-Center-is-incorrectly-locking-my-pri-files